# Open Query Error: The (maximum) expected data length is 100, while the returned data length is 14592

Tags: mysql, database

I need to extract some data from ERP.

The open Query fails with an error in multiple fields on same table.

The Error OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' for linked server 'MY_ERP_SERVER' returned data that does not match expected data length for column ''MY_Column'.

The (maximum) expected data length is xx, while the returned data length is yyyy (where xx < yyyy).

The data length is **impossible**.

I get more then *64000* some times.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should show the code/query you are using.